# Compute $\int_{\gamma}\frac{dz}{z\sin(z)}$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

Compute $\int_{\gamma}\frac{dz}{z\sin(z)}$ where $\gamma:[0,2\pi]\to \Bbb{C}$ is given by $\gamma(t)=e^{it}$

Im having a problem with this integral since, $\frac{1}{\sin(z)}$ is not holomorphic in the unit disc. I tried by doing series expansion but Im getting nowhere. Any hint?

Answer (score 5):

The only singularity of $f(z)=1/(z \sin z)$ in the unit circle is at the origin. There, we have the Laurent-series
$$ f(z) = \frac{1}{z [z -z^3/6 + O(z^5)]} = \frac{1}{z^2} + \frac{1}{6} + O(z^2) .$$

The integral you try to find, can then be obtained either by residue theorem (of simply integrating the Laurent series. We have that $$\text{Res}_{z=0} f(z) =0$$ and thus your integral vanishes.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer, also it has been a while, may you please explain the step from $\frac{1}{z[z-z^{3}/6 + O(z^5)]}$ to $\frac{1}{z^2} + \frac{1}{6} + O(z^2)$ ?