# Residue of $\frac{1}{f}$ by $f$'s Taylor series, integrating $\frac{1}{z^2\sin(z)}$ over the unit circle.

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

I wish to calculate the integral $\int_{\partial B(0,1)} \frac{1}{z^2 \sin(z)}$, the integrand has a pole of order 3 at $0$, so I tried to calculate the residue of the integrand at $0$. I found very similar post which do so for $\frac{1}{z\sin(z)}$ : [Compute $\int_{\gamma}\frac{dz}{z\sin(z)}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1471344/compute-int-gamma-fracdzz-sinz) . I don't understand the step: $\frac{1}{z\cdot(z-z^3/6 + O(z^5) )} = \frac{1}{z^2} - \frac{1}{6} + O(z^2)$, and in general can one generalize the method such that by knowing $\frac{1}{\sum _0^\infty a_n(z-z_0)^n}$ to obtain the residue of $\frac{1}{f}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some more details:
\begin{align}
\frac1{z\sin z}&=\frac 1{z\Bigl(z-\cfrac{z^3}6+O(z^5)\Bigr)}=\frac 1{z^2\Bigl(1-\cfrac{z^2}6+O(z^4)\Bigr)}=\frac 1{z^2}\cdot\Bigl(1+\cfrac{z^2}6+O(z^4)\Bigr)\\
&=\frac 1{z^2}+\frac16+\frac 1{z^2}O(z^4)=\frac 1{z^2}+\frac16+O(z^2)
\end{align}

Comment: The third equality $\frac{1}{z^2(1-\frac{z^2}{6} + O(z^4))} = \frac{1}{z^2} \cdot \frac{1}{1-\frac{z^2}{6} + O(z^4)}$  so how to obtain $\frac{1}{z^2} \cdot (1+\frac{z^2}{6} + O(z^4))$  ?

Comment: That's Taylor's formula for $\frac 1{1-u}$ + substitution.